# MantisBT - private Category

Tags: mantis

in my newly created MantisBT I created 2 categories. One for bugs and one for tasks. While the bugs should be reported by any user who wants to, the tasks should be only accessible by developers.
So, is there any way to make a category not visible for users with a certain access level?

Edit: Maybe to make this more general, how can I set what a certain access level is allowed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for 'private' categories in MantisBT at the moment. I suggest that you

- create two Projects, Tasks and Bugs
- set the visibility of the Bugs project to 'private'
- add only the developer to the Bugs project